# Google Spreadsheets refuses to leave out commas

Tags: google-sheets

On the spreadsheet in question there is a column that contains plain numbers in a particular sequence. As an example: `3040513`, `3050513`, `3060513` etc.

Sometimes when typing in the next sequenced number it will automatically add commas, so the number comes out as `3,050,513`. It also does this if I highlight a row of numbers above to use as a "guide" to add numbers automatically to rows below.

I have tried to set the column format as plain text and as no decimals to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you share a doc with us?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure *Plain Text* didn't do the trick? In my spreadsheet, it worked.

1. Highlight the cells
2. Click *Format* → *Number* → **Plain Text**

Here's a reference, saying the same thing with more words: [Remove Commas](http://yourbusiness.azcentral.com/remove-commas-google-spreadsheets-3200.html).

Comment: While this works fine for integers, it makes it impossible to restrict the number of decimal places.  If you tell the the spreadsheet that a cell is restricted to N decimal places, it becomes a number, and gets commas.

Answer (score 2):

If setting the column as plain text doesn't work, try changing the format to Automatic.

Click Format → Number → Automatic